# HTML Entity Vs. Unicode Code Point Which To Use

Tags: html, unicode, entity, html-entities, html-encode

This might be a rookie question, but I've pondered it and can't find a definitive answer.

What should you use when coding out a special character in your website? HTML Entity Decimal,  HTML Entity Hexadecimal, or Unicode Code Point.  What are the differences and Best to use?

Example:
ō

- Unicode Code Point `U+014D`
- HTML Entity (Decimal) `&#333;`
- HTML Entity (Hexadecimal) `&#x014D;`
- URL Escape Code `%C5%8D`

https://graphemica.com/%C5%8D

Comment: In HTML, only the second and third ones are valid. They're called character references by the way, not entities. The entity would be &omacr;. But why not just write ō instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5: which is better - using a character entity vs using a character directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808098/html5-which-is-better-using-a-character-entity-vs-using-a-character-directly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should just write the literal character. If you write a web page in Japanese you don't convert every character to an HTML entity...

If you have difficulty typing the character, it may make sense to use a named entity, like `&Psi;`. As long as you aren't making a whole document into entities it doesn't matter if you have a few characters as entities rather than literal characters.

Also two of your four options are not applicable:

- Unicode Code Point U+014D: You can't write "unicode code points" to anything, they're not a data format, it's a lookup number for the Unicode spec.
- URL Escape Code %C5%8D: This doesn't work in HTML, it's only used in query strings.